# Facebook share not working in mobile fancybox

Tags: javascript, facebook, mobile, fancybox, share

Updating issue:

We have a Facebook share feature that appears on a page and also in a FancyBox.

Desktop: It works on both the page and the FancyBox.

Mobile: When on a page, it opens a FB popup that is unusable - e.g. it has "login to facebook" text but no clickable button.  When on a fancy box (i.e. there is already a popup), clicking the share link does nothing.

Thanks in advance for your ideas and help.

```
<?php if ($this->is_facebook && $this->oauth_fb_key) { ?>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo $this->oauth_fb_key; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $this->site_name; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->item['url']; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->item['title']; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $this->item['description']; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="https:<?php echo $this->item['image']; ?>"/>
    <?php if ($this->og_namespace) { ?>
        <meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo $this->og_namespace; ?>:<?php echo $this->og_recipe; ?>"/>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($this->oauth_fb_key) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var loaded_fb = loaded_fb || false;
        head.ready('jquery', function() {

            $(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'https://graph.facebook.com',
         data: { id: '<?php echo $this->item['url']; ?>', scrape: true },
         success: function(result) { console.log(result); },
         async:   false
    });

                var li = $('.facebook-share-button');
                button = $('<li class="facebook-share-button"><div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $this->item['url']; ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div></li>');
                if (li.size()) {
                    li.remove();
                }
                button.prependTo('.event-load-buttons');

                if (!loaded_fb) {
                    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
                            appId: '<?php echo $this->oauth_fb_key; ?>',
                            status: true,
                            cookie: true,
                            xfbml: true
                        });

                    };

                    // Load the SDK asynchronously
                    (function(d, s, id) {
                        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        js = d.createElement(s);
                        js.id = id;
                        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

                    loaded_fb = true;
                } else {
                    var interval = setInterval(function() {
                        if (typeof FB !== 'undefined') {
                            FB.XFBML.parse();
                            clearInterval(interval);
                        }
                    }, 20);
                }




            });
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That looks quite convoluted and needlessly complex … why are you scraping the URL on each page load? And since you are using PHP already, why are you inserting the Like button using jQuery? Just put it into the document right way by outputting it via PHP – then you can scrap all that “is the SDK loaded already or not” code completely, you just initialize it on page load, and done.

Comment: Tx CBroe.  For some reason, fb wasn't scraping our pages: on the first click, the fb scraper was triggered, and then we had to click again to actually share.  We solved that by initiating a scrape here.  However, when we click the share button on mobile, it fails completely.  No popup is triggered.  Any ideas on that?  Tx!

Comment: If you need to do that, then you should do it _once_ when you publish a new article (or update an existing one) – that is functionality that belongs into the back-end, doing it on every page load is rather nonsense.

Comment: OK, good idea. We are fixing old code so will take your suggestion and move the scrape to publish.  Any ideas on MOBILE issue?  Tx.

Comment: I’d clean up the code first (as I said, one single initialization of the SDK should be enough, if you output the Like button code server-side already – no `setInterval`, no `FB.XFBML.parse` call), and see if the problem on mobile persists.

Comment: CBroe, I realize the reason it is not working is that it is inside a fancy box.  That doesn't seem to be a problem on desktop but on mobile, it won't open another window.  Any addtl ideas?